# SQLServer 2014 does not open the local server

Tags: sql-server

My SQL server management Studio 2014 doesn't open local server...

I am try:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

and:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

and so:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

I have installed it :
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Instead of using `localhost`, use `.` if you're not using Express and `.\SQLEXPRESS` if you are. You can type services.msc into your start menu search and see what SQL Server Instance names you have there, and whether or not they're running.

Answer (score 1):

With command line, type `SQLCMD -L` to see a list of installed instances on your machine.  Check to see if the instances you are using are on the list, if not, this list will tell you what is installed on your machine.

Hope this helps!